# Issue with MBR / Grub

Tags: ubuntu, windows, bios, mbr, partition-table

Some issue with my hard disk -- when mounted inside the laptop, the system is booting into a black screen.
Even when I change the boot preference to boot with a usb stick, its still getting stuck at the black screen.
If I remove the hard disk - it then boots fine from the usb.

I can access my data and see the partition table when I mount the hard disk with an external SATA mount into another laptop.

*Supporting Info*:
I had windows 10 + Ubuntu. Due to some issues with grub, I deleted the linux partitions and fixed MBR with:
lilo -M /dev/sdb mbr

*I'm guessing some mess up with the MBR is causing the BIOS to try to read it and then going in a hung state, but then not sure why setting the boot order is getting ignored.*

**Any way is fine, I just want to make the harddisk Bootable (preferably with the Windows). Please advise.**

I'm attaching screenshot of my partition table (/dev/sdb is the hard disk in trouble; mounted externally):
[image: /dev/sdb is the hard disk in trouble; mounted externally]

.

Comment: If you are not booting from the disk, the MBR should not even be read at all.